# Exception connection refused

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

I'm building a POC using the Spring 5 webflux, SpringBoot 2 and Reactive MongoDB. While building the project using the maven plugin, I'm getting the error Mongodb connection error like following :-

```
2018-06-11 10:16:35.415  INFO 16040 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$2.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$2.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:145) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:327) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:343) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:27017
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2018-06-11 10:16:35.824  INFO 16040 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted

2018-06-11 10:16:35.852  INFO 16040 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.ipc.netty.tcp.BlockingNettyContext     : Started HttpServer on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:60327
2018-06-11 10:16:35.855  INFO 16040 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 60327
```

**Following is my application.properties file :-**

```
#spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/webflux_demo

#mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=webflux_demo

#logging
logging.level.org.springframework.data=debug
logging.level.=error
```

**Pom.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myspringboot.microservice.webflux</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-webflux</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Please advise what could be the issue here? Do I need to install MongoDB in my machine explicitly and run before running this project. I believe MongoDB instance will run by itself as SpringBoot will instantiate it during the runtime.

Thank you

Comment: It says "connection refused". Most likely because you are not running a `mongod` daemon. Did you install the MongoDB Database and run it? Because the error suggests you have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Please verify mongodb is installed by `db.version()` from mongo console.

2.Verify mongo service status is running or not.

3.If running then check service port.

If any of the three fails then first resolve them.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. How come I had to run mongod when this should refer to an embedded mongodb instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can start the mongod process by issuing the following command:

sudo systemctl start mongod

If you receive an error similar to the following when starting mongod:

Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
Run the following command first:

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
Then run the start command above again.

2
Verify that MongoDB has started successfully.
sudo systemctl status mongod

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using embedded mongo. After changing build.gradle, it needs refresh.

Solution - Refresh gradle project [ right click project in eclipse/ similar for other IDE]
and run application.

It will download...mongodb-win32-x86_64 or similar and starts normally